# Why to create global objects in heap?

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory

When i read a tutorial of ogre3d, opengl or physics framework, all the objects(Window,SceneManager object) are created in heap?

are they using heap for "the object pointer destroyed but the heap object still there(outlive a object)" ?

sorry for bad English

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], but even then it may be hard to guess someone else's intention

Comment: When talking about 3d or physics frameworks, the term "object" means something different from the same term in relation to C++ programing. What do *you* mean by the term "object"? Do you mean objects in the C++ way, where you can create an object using the `new` C++ keyword? If you do, then please edit your question as Ogre3d isn't really relevant, and please elaborate on the problem you have and what you are wondering about.

Comment: In general, objects can only be created on the stack or the heap. The stack is limited in size and in its lifetime, so in general, larger objects that need to live a long time will tend to be created on the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible reasons:

1. It's just incidental, and unnecessary:

   - Author didn't know any better. Not all tutorial authors are experts, nor do they necessarily hone their tutorial code to perfection.
   - Author modeled the tutorial based on a full project where it was important, but the reason was lost in the tutorial.
2. Because the objects were big. This is argument against using automatic objects, but not really relevant for static.
3. Because the initialization needed to be delayed.

   - This allows better error handling, and side-steps the *static initialization order fiasco*.
   - This could also be achieved with *initialization on first use* idiom that doesn't require dynamic allocation.
4. The framework has chosen to use a special singleton pattern that relies on the singletons to be allocated dynamically, since the framework will delete them automatically. I know this is the case for `Ogre::LogManager` for example.